# Access more than one type of file with Dir() in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, directory

I want to find .jpg file in different folders:

```
file = Dir(folder & "\*.jpg")
```

Is there a way to also find png images? I'd like it if I don't have to change all my code.

Comment: Your code should search for all files, then, during iteration filter it for the necessary extensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, try the next way:

```
   Dim file as string, folder as string, arrExt
    folder = "your folder path"
    file = Dir(folder & "\*.*")
    Do While file <> ""
        arrExt = split(file, ".")
        If UCase(arrExt(Ubound(arrExt))) = "JPG" Or _
           UCase(arrExt(Ubound(arrExt))) = = "PNG" Then
            ' do whatever you need
        End If
        file = Dir
    Loop
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I don't really understand what happens, but it works I guess ahahaa, I'm still quite surprised it's not possible with a more simple way

Answer (score 1):

Use `Dir(folder & "\*.*")` to list *all* files and check by hand if it is a file you are interested in, eg with a function like this:

```
Function isImage(fileName As String) As Boolean
    Dim ext As String, p As Long
    p = InStrRev(fileName, ".")
    If p = 0 Then Exit Function
    ext = LCase(Mid(fileName, p + 1))
    isImage = (ext = "jpg" Or ext = "jpeg" Or ext = "png")
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly well ! :) but above comment is more suitable for my code because I do a loop after that

Comment: Great solution. @FaneDuru's `Split()` approach would be beneficial when files have been named using multiple dots, e.g., xyz_01.01.22.jpg.

Comment: @bugdrown As I am using  `InStrRev` (which finds the *last* occurrence), it would work also with files with multiple dots.

Comment: @FunThomas Apologies, I read `InStr()`.